# d3.queue.await function not invoked

Tags: javascript, d3.js, async-await, deferred

Why is the .await function not invoked in this very little example?

http://jsfiddle.net/x2fkvsco/

HTML

```
<h1>test</h1>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

JS

```
d3.queue()
   .defer(a,1)
   .await(b,2);

function a(x){
    d3.select('#a').text("a is executing with x="+x);
}

function b(err,x){
   d3.select('#b').text("b is executing with x="+x);
}
```

Output

```
test
a is executing with x=1
```

Comment: It's in the first sentences of the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_defer): *" the callback must be invoked by the task when it finishes. "*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@altocumulus beat me to it with his insightful comment, but since an example speaks a thousand words:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <script>
    var q = d3.queue()
      .defer(a, 1, 2)
      .await(b);

    function a(x, y, callback) {
      d3.select('#a').text("a is executing with x=" + x);
      callback(null, y);
    }

    function b(err, x) {
      d3.select('#b').text("b is executing with x=" + x);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see! I would accept both answers if I could, but I will take this one.

Answer (score 4):

It's in the first sentences of the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_defer):

> the callback must be invoked by the task when it finishes.

To comply with the API you need to invoke the callback, which is supplied as the last parameter to your function `a()`:

```
function a(x, callback) {
  d3.select('#a').text("a is executing with x="+x);
  callback(null, { /* result */ });   
}
```